# How come some linux users don't have home directories?

Tags: linux, user-management

In linux I only see a `/home/[[me]]` directory. However, I know there are at least 20+ other users (*root, www-data, etc..*).

How come some users don't have user directories - and is it possible to create new users without a home directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many of these users are created as system users. On Debian/Ubuntu, you can do that with `adduser --system`. If you only want to avoid creating a home dir (not creating a system user), you can use `adduser --no-create-home`.

I'm sure, there's an equivalent for non-Debian systems (with `useradd` etc). The `useradd` manpage tells me:

```
-M Do not create the user's home directory
-r, --system Create a system account.
```

Comment: Ok, so then Ubuntu/Debian has two types of users - system and normal? Where can I find a listing of all system users then?

Comment: @Xeoncross: All users are the same - they're just used for different purposes. A "system" user account is one which doesn't belong to a person, but instead to a program. This is an Unix convention, not Debian-specific.

Comment: From the useradd manpage: System users will be created with no aging information in /etc/shadow, and their numeric identifiers are choosen [sic] in the SYS_UID_MIN-SYS_UID_MAX range, defined in /etc/login.defs, ...